# After setting a2dp, sound apps dosent work

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

all.

My sound apps doesn't work now...

Firstly, a2dp did not work.
A2dp works after running "pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover," but now, regardless of bluetooth connection, any other sound apps doesn't work.
To be precise, running an app crashes my cinnamon.

Running "pactl list" show this.

```
Module #0   Name: module-device-restore     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"       module.version = "8.0"

Module #1   Name: module-stream-restore     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #2   Name: module-card-restore   Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"       module.version = "8.0"

Module #3   Name: module-augment-properties     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"      module.version = "8.0"

Module #4   Name: module-switch-on-port-available   Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:


Module #5   Name: module-udev-detect    Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #6   Name: module-alsa-card  Argument: device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"  Usage counter: 3    Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "ALSA Card"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #7   Name: module-bluetooth-policy   Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau"      module.description = "When a bluetooth sink or source is added, load module-loopback"       module.version = "8.0"

Module #8   Name: module-bluetooth-discover     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"         module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #9   Name: module-bluez5-discover    Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"         module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #10  Name: module-native-protocol-unix   Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"       module.version = "8.0"

Module #11  Name: module-default-device-restore     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #12  Name: module-rescue-streams     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "When a sink/source is removed, try to move its streams to the default sink/source"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #13  Name: module-always-sink    Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Colin Guthrie"         module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #14  Name: module-intended-roles     Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based on intended roles of devices"       module.version = "8.0"

Module #15  Name: module-suspend-on-idle    Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"      module.version = "8.0"

Module #16  Name: module-systemd-login  Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"      module.version = "8.0"

Module #17  Name: module-position-event-sounds  Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Lennart Poettering"        module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."         module.version = "8.0"

Module #18  Name: module-filter-heuristics  Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Colin Guthrie"         module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"        module.version = "8.0"

Module #19  Name: module-filter-apply   Argument:   Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Colin Guthrie"         module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"      module.version = "8.0"

Module #20  Name: module-bluez5-device  Argument: path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C4_0B_CB_7D_8F_44    Usage counter: 1    Properties:         module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"         module.description = "BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio sink and source"      module.version = "8.0"

Module #21  Name: module-loopback   Argument: source="bluez_source.C4_0B_CB_7D_8F_44" source_dont_move="true" sink_input_properties="media.role=music"  Usage counter: n/a  Properties:         module.author = "Pierre-Louis Bossart"      module.description = "Loopback from source to sink"         module.version
= "8.0"

Sink #0     State: RUNNING  Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo   Driver: module-alsa-card.c  Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz     Channel Map: front-left,front-right     Owner Module: 6     Mute: no    Volume: front-left: 42558 /  65% / -11.25 dB,   front-right: 42558 /  65% / -11.25 dB
            balance 0.00    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB     Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor  Latency: 46080 usec, configured 66666 usec  Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY      Properties:         alsa.resolution_bits = "16"         device.api = "alsa"         device.class = "sound"      alsa.class = "generic"      alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"       alsa.name = "ALC255 Analog"         alsa.id = "ALC255 Analog"       alsa.subdevice = "0"        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"        alsa.device = "0"       alsa.card = "0"         alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xef128000 irq 129"         alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"      device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"         device.bus = "pci"      device.vendor.id = "8086"       device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"        device.product.id = "9d71"      device.form_factor = "internal"         device.string = "front:0"       device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"      device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"       device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"       device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"         alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC255"      alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0255,10431520,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"         device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"     Ports:      analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)       analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)    Active Port: analog-output-speaker  Formats:        pcm

Source #0   State: IDLE     Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo    Driver: module-alsa-card.c  Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz     Channel Map: front-left,front-right     Owner Module: 6     Mute: no    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB     Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo     Latency: 0 usec, configured 371519 usec     Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY   Properties:         device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"      device.class = "monitor"        alsa.card = "0"         alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xef128000 irq 129"         alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"      device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"         device.bus = "pci"      device.vendor.id = "8086"       device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"        device.product.id = "9d71"      device.form_factor = "internal"         device.string = "0"         module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"         device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"     Formats:        pcm

Source #1   State: RUNNING  Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo     Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo   Driver: module-alsa-card.c  Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz     Channel Map: front-left,front-right     Owner Module: 6     Mute: yes   Volume: front-left: 44652 /  68% / -10.00 dB,   front-right: 44652 /  68% / -10.00 dB
            balance 0.00    Base Volume: 6554 /  10% / -60.00 dB    Monitor of Sink: n/a    Latency: 0 usec, configured 40000 usec  Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY      Properties:         alsa.resolution_bits = "16"         device.api = "alsa"         device.class = "sound"      alsa.class = "generic"      alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"       alsa.name = "ALC255 Analog"         alsa.id = "ALC255 Analog"       alsa.subdevice = "0"        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"        alsa.device = "0"       alsa.card = "0"         alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xef128000 irq 129"         alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"      device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"         device.bus = "pci"      device.vendor.id = "8086"       device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"        device.product.id = "9d71"      device.form_factor = "internal"         device.string = "front:0"       device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"      device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"       device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"       device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"         alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC255"      alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0255,10431520,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"         device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"     Ports:      analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700)   Active Port: analog-input-mic   Formats:        pcm

Source #2   State: RUNNING  Name: bluez_source.C4_0B_CB_7D_8F_44    Description: Redmi  Driver: module-bluez5-device.c  Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz     Channel Map: front-left,front-right     Owner Module: 20    Mute: no    Volume: front-left: 66191 / 101% / 0.26 dB,   front-right: 66191 / 101% / 0.26 dB
            balance 0.00    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB     Monitor of Sink: n/a    Latency: 26947 usec, configured 135294 usec     Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY      Properties:         bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_source"      device.description = "Redmi"        device.string = "C4:0B:CB:7D:8F:44"         device.api = "bluez"        device.class = "sound"      device.bus = "bluetooth"        device.form_factor = "phone"        bluez.path
= "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C4_0B_CB_7D_8F_44"       bluez.class = "0x5a020c"        bluez.alias = "Redmi"       device.icon_name = "audio-card-bluetooth"   Ports:      phone-input: Phone (priority: 0, available)     Active Port: phone-input    Formats:        pcm

Sink Input #0   Driver: module-loopback.c   Owner Module: 21    Client: n/a     Sink: 0     Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz     Channel Map: front-left,front-right     Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""    Corked: no  Mute: no    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00    Buffer Latency: 180181 usec     Sink Latency: 45024 usec    Resample method: speex-float-1  Properties:         media.role = "music"        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:music"         media.name = "Loopback from Redmi"      media.icon_name = "audio-card-bluetooth"

Source Output #0    Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Client: 2   Source: 1   Sample Specification: float32le 1ch 25Hz    Channel Map: mono   Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate
= "25"  format.channels = "1"  format.channel_map = "\"mono\""  Corked: no  Mute: no    Volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00    Buffer Latency: 0 usec  Source Latency: 435 usec    Resample method: peaks  Properties:         application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"      media.name = "Peak detect"      application.name = "cinnamon"       native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"         native-protocol.version = "30"      application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"         application.version = "3.2.4"       application.process.id = "3090"         application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "python2.7"        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"       module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.gnome.VolumeControl"

Source Output #2    Driver: module-loopback.c   Owner Module: 21    Client: n/a     Source: 2   Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz     Channel Map: front-left,front-right     Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""    Corked: no  Mute: no    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00    Buffer Latency: 0 usec  Source Latency: 27368 usec  Resample method: n/a    Properties:         media.role = "abstract"         module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-media-role:abstract"       media.name = "Loopback to Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"         media.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"

Source Output #3    Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Client: 7   Source: 1   Sample Specification: float32le 1ch 25Hz    Channel Map: mono   Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate
= "25"  format.channels = "1"  format.channel_map = "\"mono\""  Corked: no  Mute: no    Volume: mono: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00    Buffer Latency: 0 usec  Source Latency: 635 usec    Resample method: peaks  Properties:         application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"      media.name = "Peak detect"      application.name = "cinnamon"       native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"         native-protocol.version = "30"      application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"         application.version = "3.2.4"       application.process.id = "11167"        application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "python2.7"        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"       module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.gnome.VolumeControl"

Client #0   Driver: module-systemd-login.c  Owner Module: 16    Properties:         application.name = "Login Session c1"       systemd-login.session = "c1"

Client #1   Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Properties:         application.name = "Cinnamon Volume Control Media Keys"         native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"         native-protocol.version = "30"      application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"      application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"         application.version = "3.2.4"       application.process.id = "1928"         application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "cinnamon-settings-daemon"         application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"

Client #2   Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Properties:         application.name = "cinnamon"       native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"         native-protocol.version = "30"      application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"      application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"         application.version = "3.2.4"       application.process.id = "3090"         application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "python2.7"        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"

Client #5   Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Properties:         application.name = "Cinnamon Volume Control"        native-protocol.peer
= "UNIX socket client"      native-protocol.version = "30"      application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"      application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"         application.version = "3.2.4"       application.process.id = "10501"        application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "cinnamon"         application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"

Client #7   Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Properties:         application.name = "cinnamon"       native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"         native-protocol.version = "30"      application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"      application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"         application.version = "3.2.4"       application.process.id = "11167"        application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "python2.7"        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"

Client #8   Driver: protocol-native.c   Owner Module: 10    Properties:         application.name = "pactl"      native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"         native-protocol.version = "30"      application.process.id = "11392"        application.process.user = "lesbeauxxx"         application.process.host = "lesbeauxxx-laptop"      application.process.binary = "pactl"        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"        window.x11.display = ":0"       application.process.machine_id = "5ab3c275b7304ed3b8aeef9ffcc37eb4"         application.process.session_id = "c1"

Card #0     Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3    Driver: module-alsa-card.c  Owner Module: 6     Properties:         alsa.card = "0"         alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xef128000 irq 129"         alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"      device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"         device.bus = "pci"      device.vendor.id = "8086"       device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"        device.product.id = "9d71"      device.form_factor = "internal"         device.string = "0"         device.description = "Built-in Audio"       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"         device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"     Profiles:       input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)       output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)       output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)       output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: yes)         output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output
+ Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5460, available: yes)        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: yes)      output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 360, available: yes)        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 300, available: yes)        output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 360, available: yes)      output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: yes)        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)      output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)         output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround
5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)         output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)       output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround
7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)         output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: yes)        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)      output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)         output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround
5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)         output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: yes)       output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround
7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)         off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo    Ports:      analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec)           Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"             Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo       analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec)           Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"             Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo      analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"           Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo      hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)           Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"          Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo      hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)             Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"          Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)             Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"          Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo

Card #1     Name: bluez_card.C4_0B_CB_7D_8F_44  Driver: module-bluez5-device.c  Owner Module: 20    Properties:         device.description = "Redmi"        device.string = "C4:0B:CB:7D:8F:44"         device.api = "bluez"        device.class = "sound"      device.bus = "bluetooth"        device.form_factor = "phone"        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C4_0B_CB_7D_8F_44"        bluez.class = "0x5a020c"        bluez.alias = "Redmi"       device.icon_name = "audio-card-bluetooth"   Profiles:       a2dp_source: High Fidelity Capture (A2DP Source) (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 10, available: yes)       headset_audio_gateway: Headset Audio Gateway (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 20, available: no)      off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)    Active Profile: a2dp_source     Ports:      phone-output: Phone (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)            Part of profile(s): headset_audio_gateway       phone-input: Phone (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)             Part of profile(s): a2dp_source, headset_audio_gateway
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: to reset alsa didn't work, and alsamixer looks fine...

Comment: To run Rhythmbox from terminal emulator does not crash and sound works well. Neither does from launch menu. ONLY running from sound tray icon crashes...